# Building a war file that can be deployed by Maven Tomcat plugin

Tags: tomcat, maven, war, vaadin

This is not technically a programming question, but a question about an error I get when deploying my war file from a Maven project.

The error I'm getting after I build my war file, run Tomcat7, and open a browser is:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /vaadin-test/

type Status report

message /vaadin-test/

description The requested resource (/vaadin-test/) is not available.
```

I am using [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com) as my web app platform.  I have a very simple project I'm trying to run for testing.  I'm using `tomcat7-maven-plugin` and `maven-war-plugin` in my POM file.  The war plugin configuration looks like this (I don't think I even need the filtering):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>

            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                <warName>vaadin-test</warName>

                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>

                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The web.xml looks like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.catalystitservices.vaadin.TestApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test-app</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Whether I try to run `mvn tomcat7:run` or deploy the created war file to an external Tomcat server (via the manager page) I get the same error.  This leads me to think I'm not building the war file correctly.  There are no error logs that I can find (but maybe I'm missing them).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not have `<finalName>` specified in your `<build>` block,
Maven will create a war name in the following format:

```
vaadin-test-1.0.war
```

Where `vaadin-test` is the artifact name and `1.0` is the version string.

Therefore the url you have to refer to is `/vaadin-test-1.0` not `/vaadin-test`

In addition your vaadin servlet is bound to a url /test-app so after you add the finalName tag , a complete URL should be something like: `/vaadin-test/test-app`

NB! Please note that `1.0` here is merely an example, please consult your own `pom.xml` for the real value

Comment: I can see my war file and it looks like `vaadin-test.war`.  Also, the Tomcat manager tells me that the URL is vaadin-test.  But I will try adding a finalName to my `maven-war-plugin`.

Comment: It goes to the build block, not to maven-war-plugin. In addition, try to append /test-app to the URL like this: /vaadin-test/test-app

Comment: I changed finalName to vaadin-test and the INFO message for Maven said `Running war on http://localhost:9090/VaadinTest`.  When I run this URL I get the same error.  When I run `localhost:9090/vaadin-test` and get my browser saying it can't find the URL.

Comment: Adding `test-app` to the URL did the trick.  I'm getting a new error now, but that's another post.  Thanks.